# Will TestFlight beta testers automatically download app once it is released without pre-ordering it in AppStore?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

My mobile app is in pre-order mode right now.

I'm inviting different people to external beta-tests.

If these people don't make a pre-order in AppStore, will my app be automatically downloaded from AppStore on their devices when it is released?

Or if I want to ask them to also pre-order it in AppStore

Thank you in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, test flight is only for people to test the beta versions of an app. You can upgrade beta versions. Beta versions have a limited life time (1 month usually) . After this delay , the app will no more work. User will not be able to replace with App Store version freely. If you want, you can give them gift code to enable them to download from App Store when app is available.

Comment: @PtitXav thank you!! could you please clarify what is gift code and how to get it?

Comment: When your App is in AppStore you can generate up to 100 promo codes (as my app are free I have not the option). It is somewhere when you setup your app in AppStore Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External beta-test is only accessible via `Test Flight` app, if they accept the invitation they will be able to install it from testflight app.

Comment: so they will be notified in test flight, that the app is available for downloading fro AppStore?

Comment: Yes, the first time they will be notified by email and required to accept invitation then they will be notified that there is an update via Test Flight app